# Make UINavigationBar title be user editable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

How do I make `UINavigationBar` title to be user editable, I've tried setting the `titleView` to be a textfield however it doesn't look the same.. It's missing that outline or drop shadow. I'm aiming for it to look like the default one.

This is what i'm implementing at the moment:

```
 _titleField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 26)];
[_titleField setDelegate:self];
_titleField.text = _bugDoc.data.title;
_titleField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
_titleField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_titleField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = _titleField;
```

Comment: You are making custom navigation Bar ??

Comment: @Manohar, no i'm not. Just looking for a method of having a user be able to tap on the navBar title to edit. As of now, I have a textField set as the titleView but it doesn't look the same, as its just text.

Comment: Please check my answer. Set your Frame according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadTitle];
}
- (void)loadTitle
{
    txtField_navTitle = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x,7,self.view.bounds.size.width,31)];
    txtField_navTitle.delegate = self;
    [txtField_navTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    txtField_navTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    txtField_navTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    txtField_navTitle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    txtField_navTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    txtField_navTitle.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    txtField_navTitle.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:txtField_navTitle];
    txtField_navTitle.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    txtField_navTitle.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    txtField_navTitle.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
    [txtField_navTitle release];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    self.title = textField.text;
    return YES;
}
```

**Please dont forget to** `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: This is already what i'm implementing though, like i stated in my original post I have it working but this method doesn't look like the original navBar title look. The navBar title bar originally has like a dropshadow or some kind of effect on it.

Comment: how so? that's what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Any number of times, he can continuously press on it.

Comment: I'm using the default blue navigation bar if it makes a difference. No, it still isn't working. take a look at a navBar made with [self.navigationItem.title = @"Something" as compared to your method. the way the title is drawn looks different.

Comment: Its the font type problem. if you know what is the default font type for Navigation Bar then let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way this works for me.

```
   // Custom Navigation Title.

     UILabel* tlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 40)];
     tlabel.text=self.title;
     tlabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
     tlabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
     tlabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:7.0/255.0 green:26.0/255.0 blue:66.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
     tlabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
     tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
     self.navigationItem.titleView=tlabel;
```